# Reference a custom CSS file inside my seattle.html

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, development, master-page, css

I want to reference a custom CSS file inside my `seattle.html` file.
currently I find the following in the default `seattle.html` master page:

```
<link href="http://sharepointdev:12341/sites/mirror3/_layouts/15/1033/styles/corev15.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://sharepointdev:12341/sites/mirror3/_layouts/15/1033/styles/searchv15.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

so I simply added a reference to my custom css as follow, after the above links:

```
<link href="http://sharepointdev:12341/sites/mirror3/Style Library/Custom CSS/MyCustomeCss.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

but this did not work, so I have these questions:

1. By default `seattle.html` contains a direct reference to the server name and port, as follow `<link href="http://sharepointdev:12341/sites/mirror3/_layouts/15/1033/styles. /corev15.css"` so now let say I backup, then restore the site collection to a new server will the references break ?
2. When I added the following `<link href="http://sharepointdev:12341/sites/mirror3/Style Library/Custom CSS/MyCustomeCss.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />` to reference my custom css, this changes were not reflected inside the `seattle.master` page ?
3. The custom CSS did not apply to my current styles, while if I directly write the following to the s`eattle.master` it will work `<SharePoint:CssRegistration name="<% $SPUrl:~SiteCollection/Style Library/Custom CSS/MyCustomeCss.css %>" After="corev4.css" runat="server"/>`

Answer (score 1):

You can try following taken from [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/123285/21421). It is recommended for adding in html master page.

```
<!--SPM:<SharePoint:CssRegistration ID="CSSCustom" Name="&lt;% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/SiteAssets/css/FileName.css %&gt;" runat="server" After="Themable/corev15.css"/>-->
```

I did this in ugly way!

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/sites/IFICTeamSite/SiteAssets/MasterPageCss/masterPageCustom.css" ms-design-css-conversion="no" />
```

**ms-design-css-conversion="no"** is very important if you wish to apply ugly way! see [my answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/128695/21421)

Answer (score 0):

**First question**:

I have created this CSS

[image]

On my `seattle.html` I add this line:

[image]

And the result is this:

[image]

**Second question**:

Try to add your CSS just above the `head` closing tag, because as you know HTMLand CSS are sequentials so all your styles will be overwritten if another CSS execute after yours.

**Third question**:

To this apply the answer above, and try to check in the master page, just in case

Comment: can you advice what do you mean by your first answer, now i have the custom css inside the style library for the site collection,, but if i write the following inside the seatle.html just before the </head> tag "<!--SPM:<SharePoint:CssRegistration Name="/Style Library/Custom CSS/MyCustomeCss.css" runat="server"/>" no effect for the custom .css file as if the seatle.html is unable to load the .css file,.....

Comment: I edit my previus answer

Comment: Now inside the default Seatle.html they use the following syntax "<!--SPM:<SharePoint:CssRegistration Name="/Style Library/customcss/MyCustomCss.css" runat="server"/>-->" rather than adding <link href="..> . so what are the differences between using <link> & using <!--SPM:<SharePoint:CssRegistration ?

Comment: also one thing to mention if i use <link href="/style library/CSS/test.css" then all site collections will be referencing the test.css at the root site collection and not the one realted to each site collection ? is this correct ? can i add something such as "~SiteCollection/Style Library/CSS" instead ?

Comment: Use SharePoint:CssRegistration is exactly the same as using link, if you check the source code of your page you will not see a SharePoint:CssRegistration css you will see a link tag