# SharePoint online refer custom css and javascript in MasterPage (Site Assets)

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-online, master-page

How to add references to css and js files in HTML master pages. The files are residing in SharePoint libraries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After trying out different options available online, I was able to achieve it by

JavaScript

```
<!--SPM:<SharePoint:ScriptLink ID="ConfigurationScriptLink" Name="~sitecollection/SiteAssets/js/FileName.js" runat="server"/>-->
```

CSS

```
<!--SPM:<SharePoint:CssRegistration ID="CSSCustom" Name="&lt;% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/SiteAssets/css/FileName.css %&gt;" runat="server" After="Themable/corev15.css"/>-->
```

Answer (score 0):

I have added it following way. May be very odd!

**CSS**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/sites/IFICTeamSite/SiteAssets/MasterPageCss/masterPageCustom.css" ms-design-css-conversion="no" />
```

Comment: Using `CssRegistration` has lot of advantages, for example `After` will make sure the styles get applied after SharePoint styles (this ensures our custom styles take precedence)